# ASP.NET Core MVC controller receives null for input parameter from ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ajax call:

```
...
$("#testBtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/profile/GuestList",
        data: {"keytype": "1"},
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
           ...
        }
    });
});
...
```

and my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GuestList([FromBody]string keytype)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

So, inititally I wanted to send an enum type, but that didnt work, so I wanted to send an int with value `1` and I kept getting only 0, then I added `[FromBody]` and it was the same, at last I switched to string just in case, and now Im getting a null value.

Where I went wrong in all this variations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create class

```
public class KeyTypeViewModel
{
    public string Keytype { get; set; }
}
```

Fix action by removing [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GuestList(KeyTypeViewModel viewModel)
```

And fix ajax by removing contentType: "application/json" :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/profile/GuestList",
        data: {keytype: "1"},
        method: "POST",
       success: function (data) {
           ...
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Dto that has property keytype.

```
public class SomeDto
{
    public string Keytype { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GuestList([FromBody]SomeDto dto)
```

Comment: but theres no really need to wrap one property into whole class?

Comment: if you see in Post ajax call you are sending an object {"keytype": "1"}.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your data in your Ajax call to a string as you are using string as input parameter in your POST method.

```
...
$("#testBtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/profile/GuestList",
        data:  "1",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
           ...
        }
    });
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You must stringify your data.

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/profile/GuestList",
   data: JSON.stringify({"keytype": "1"}),
   method: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function (data) {
           ...
        }
    });
```